# A very big sum - Hacker Rank

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I am trying to solve "A very big sum" challenge on Hacker Rank: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/a-very-big-sum/problem

In there I have to sum all the numbers in the array given so I came up with two solutions:

**First solution**

```
function aVeryBigSum(ar){
  let sum = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < ar.length; i++){
     sum += i;
   }
}
```

**Second Solution**

```
function(ar){
 let sum = ar.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  accumulator + currentValue;
    });
}
```

But none of them work and I don´t know why, I am thiniking maybe I am not writing it as Hacker Rank wants me to but I am not sure

Comment: Might have something to do with the fact that you aren't returning anything in either function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sum += i;` should be `sum += ar[i];`

Also return sum

```
function aVeryBigSum(ar){
  let sum = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < ar.length; i++){
     sum += ar[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Also reducer function should be like

```
function a(ar){
  let sum = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
  return ar.reduce(sum);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your first solution, you should index the array instead of just adding up the indexes:

```
function aVeryBigSum(ar){
  let sum = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < ar.length; i++){
     sum += ar[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

To sum the array with reduce:

```
function aVeryBigSum(ar){
  return ar.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
}
```

Also, note that you should return values in the functions.
Although this works for arrays with small numbers, you should think about what can happen if the sum gets [very large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin). (See the *note* section on HackerRank.)

Answer (score 1):

you can also use this one

```
    function aVeryBigSum(ar) {
    // Write your code here
   let sum = 0;
    ar.map((num) => {
        sum += num
    })
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

both of your solutions do not RETURN the sum

```js
function aVeryBigSum(ar) {
    let sum = 0;
    ar.forEach(s =>{
    sum += s;
  });
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: You should help explain, why the OPs solutions aren't working and why this answer works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle all edge cases and corner cases on these HackerRank challenges. Observe comments, this passes all.

```
// ** Input **
const input1 = [1000000001, 1000000002, 1000000003, 1000000004, 1000000005]
const input2 = [5555]
const input3 = '10'

// ** Solution **
function aVeryBigSum(ar) {

  // Declare Working Variable
  let sum = ar

  // If Already Integer >> Return as Sum
  if (typeof sum == 'number') {
    return sum
  }

  // If String or Object
  if (typeof sum == 'string' || typeof sum == 'object') {

    // Split String into Array at Space
    if (typeof sum == 'string') { sum = sum.split(' ') }

    // Reduce
    sum = sum.reduce((a,b) => {

      // If Number > Parse as Integer
      (typeof a == 'number' && typeof b == 'number')
      a = parseInt(a)
      b = parseInt(b)

      return a += b
    }, 0)

    // Return Sum
    return sum
  }
}

// ** Testing **
console.log(aVeryBigSum(input1))
console.log(aVeryBigSum(input2))
console.log(aVeryBigSum(input3))
```

Answer (score -1):

sample input [1000000001 ,1000000002 ,1000000003, 1000000004, 1000000005]

```js
function aVeryBigSum(ar) {
  let score = 0;

  for(let i =0; i< ar.length;i++) {
    score += parseInt(ar[i].toString().substring(0));
  }

  return score;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).